Synchrosqueezing transform
I am using the Synchrosqueezing Wavelet Transform and I want to compare it to classical CWT. For this, I use a signal consisting of a chirp. Strangely, in the SST result, it looks like the chirp has less power for lower frequencies, but in fact the amplitude is constant. Does someone have an idea, why this is the case?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import ghostipy as gsp

f_sample = 1000
t = np.arange(2001) * 1/f_sample # sampling frequency: 100hz

t_segment = 0.5  # duration of each frequency segment in seconds
samples_per_segment = int(f_sample * t_segment)  #
signal = np.concatenate([
    scipy.signal.chirp(t[0:1000], f0=20, f1=80, t1=1, method='linear'),
    np.sin(2 * np.pi * 20 * t[1000:1250]),  # Next 250
    np.sin(2 * np.pi * 80 * t[1250:1500]),  # Next 250
    np.sin(2 * np.pi * 20 * t[1500:1750]),  # Next 250
    np.sin(2 * np.pi * 80 * t[1750:])   # Last 250
])

wavelet = gsp.AmorWavelet()

freq_limits = np.array([10, 100])
coeff_cwt, scales_cwt, freqs_cwt, _, _ = gsp.cwt(signal, fs=f_sample, wavelet=wavelet, freq_limits=freq_limits)
coeff_ssq, scales_ssq, freqs_ssq, _, _ = gsp.wsst(signal, fs=f_sample, wavelet=wavelet, freq_limits=freq_limits)

psd_cwt = np.abs(coeff_cwt) ** 2
psd_ssq = np.abs(coeff_ssq) ** 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
fig.suptitle("Spectrogram", fontsize="16")
g_spec = gs.GridSpec(3, 2, width_ratios=[1, 0.03], height_ratios=[1, 3, 3])

ax1 = plt.subplot(g_spec[0, 0])
ax1.set_title("Signal")
ax1.set_xlabel("Time [sec]")
ax1.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax1.set_xlim([0, 2])
ax1.plot(t[:], signal[:])

ax2 = plt.subplot(g_spec[1, 0])
c1 = ax2.pcolormesh(t ,freqs_cwt, psd_cwt, cmap="turbo")
ax2.set_title(f"CWT using Morlet wavelet")
ax2.set_xlabel("Time [seconds]")
ax2.set_ylabel("Frequency [Hz]")
# Colorbar
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(c1, cax=plt.subplot(g_spec[1, 1]), label="Power [a.u.]")
ax3 = plt.subplot(g_spec[2, 0])
c2 = ax3.pcolormesh(t ,freqs_ssq, psd_ssq, cmap="turbo")
ax3.set_title(f"SST using Morlet wavelet")
ax3.set_xlabel("Time [seconds]")
ax3.set_ylabel("Frequency [Hz]")
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(c2, cax=plt.subplot(g_spec[2, 1]), label="Power [a. u.]")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Many thanks in advance!
Roland

Did you look at the transfer function of your algorithm? Is there a filtering effect for low frequencies?

Not one that I'm aware of. The frequency re-assignment happens in https://github.com/kemerelab/ghostipy/blob/b34ec0954dbfa7fd638279e96ad58cfd04fee988/ghostipy/spectral/wsst.py#L11 and does not include filtering.

It looks like a forgotten scale or frequency factor in the integral over scales / frequencies.
In panel 2, the "power" of the CWT is either the CWT squared or its modulus, in the "norm $L_1$" convention.
The frequency-reassignment integrate the square and the synchrosqueezing the amplitude itself, with integrand $\textrm{d} f$ (or $\frac{\textrm{d} a}{a^2}$ for the wavelet timescale $a$) if your CWT is defined with the "norm $L_2$" convention, or with respect to $\textrm{d} \log f = \frac{\textrm{d}f}{|f|}$ (or $\frac{\textrm{d} a}{|a|}$) with the "norm $L_1$" convention.
The definition of the CWT with a norm $p$ is the following:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{W}_\psi[x](a,b;p)=\int x(t) \psi^*(\tfrac{t-b}{a})|a|^{-\frac{1}{p}}\textrm{d}t \quad .
\end{equation*}
The different conventions are related as follows:
$$\mathcal{W}_\psi[x](a,b;p)=|a|^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\mathcal{W}_\psi[x](a,b;p=1) \quad.$$
Integrating the square of it with two different conventions will lack a factor $|a|$ or $|f|$.
